# How to check the data and time that a table was created in IBM Netezza SQL from Aginity workbench

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows-7, netezza

My question may be simple, but, I have been searching the answer for a long time.

How to check the data and time that a table was created  in IBM Netezza SQL from Aginity workbench ?

It is very easy to find this in MS SQL server, but, I cannot figure this out in Netezza.

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    TABLENAME,
    OWNER,
    CREATEDATE 
FROM _V_TABLE 
WHERE 
OBJTYPE='TABLE';
```

Comment: Thanks ! it works, but, how to get the table last-update time ?

Comment: select * from _v_table;